# How do I create a base page in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have decided that all my WPF pages need to register a routed event.  Rather than include

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent MyEvent= EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("MyEvent", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(BasePage));
```

on every page, I decided to create a base page (named BasePage).  I put the above line of code in my base page and then changed a few of my other pages to derive from BasePage.  I can't get past this error:

> Error 12  'CTS.iDocV7.BasePage' cannot
>   be the root of a XAML file because it
>   was defined using XAML. Line 1
>   Position
>   22.   C:\Work\iDoc7\CTS.iDocV7\UI\Quality\QualityControlQueuePage.xaml    1   22  CTS.iDocV7

Does anyone know how to best create a base page when I can put events, properties, methods, etc that I want to be able to use from any wpf page?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's how I've done this in my current project.

First I've defined a class (as @Daren Thomas said - just a plain old C# class, no associated XAML file), like this (and yes, this is a real class - best not to ask):

```
public class PigFinderPage : Page
{
    /* add custom events and properties here */
}
```

Then I create a new Page and change its XAML declaration to this:

```
<my:PigFinderPage x:Class="Qaf.PigFM.WindowsClient.PenSearchPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Qaf.PigFM.WindowsClient"
    />
```

So I declare it as a PigFinderPage in the "my" namespace. Any page-wide resources you need have to be declared using a similar syntax:

```
<my:PigFinderPage.Resources>
    <!-- your resources go here -->
</my:PigFinderPage.Resources>
```

Lastly, switch to the code-behind for this new page, and change its class declaration so that it derives from your custom class rather than directly from Page, like this:

```
public partial class EarmarkSearchPage : PigFinderPage
```

Remember to keep it as a partial class.

That's working a treat for me - I can define a bunch of custom properties and events back in "PigFinderPage" and use them in all the descendants.

Comment: But how do you share your PigFinderPage Resources between all your derived pages? Your example above seems to imply you define them in each derived class' XAML - in which case if you want to declare the base resources once you are in trouble without copy & paste.

Comment: Ah yes. Any shared resources I'm using live external to the page. Some in App.xaml, some in resource dictionaries that I import as required.

Comment: Two things: end you Xaml definition with </my:PigFinderPage> and when inheriting from another assembly use: xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Qaf.PigFM.WindowsClient;assembly=QafPigFM.WindowsClient.BasePages". Don't introduce a space between ; and the assembly tag, this will cause an uncompilable project.

Answer (score 4):

Also, have a look at [Attached Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613550.aspx) and see if you can attach your event to every Page in your app. Might be easier than a custom intermediary class.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure on this one, but looking at your error, I would try to define the base class with just c# (.cs) code - do not create one with XAML, just a standard .cs file that extends the WPF Page class.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2009/11/02/creating-a-base-window-class-in-wpf.aspx) is a tutorial too !
it's pretty simple and easy.

Answer (score 1):

Little update : I just tried to do it, and it didn't work. He is what I changed to solve the problem:

1.In many forums, you will read that the sub pages must inherit from a simple cs class, without XAML. Though it works. I do inherit from a normal XAML page without any problem.

2.I replaced the following code :

```
<my:PigFinderPage x:Class="Qaf.PigFM.WindowsClient.PenSearchPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Qaf.PigFM.WindowsClient"
/>
```

with

```
<my:PigFinderPage x:Class="Qaf.PigFM.WindowsClient.PenSearchPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:my="using:Qaf.PigFM.WindowsClient"
/>
```

because when I had "clr-namespace" instead of "using", the Intellisense could recognize PigFinderPage, but not the compiler.